# How to prevent mobile Android app from tracking when you uninstall and reinstall apps?

Tags: applications, privacy

I would like to create 2 accounts for the same Android app. First one account, them remove the app, install it again and make new account. However I need to make sure that the app cannot recognize that I already installed that app in the past.

Do Android apps have ability to keep some kind of cookies or some other type of history when you uninstall it? If yes, is there any option to remove that history?

Comment: [usual ways for an app to detect your device](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/86903/131553) //If you root your device you can possibly spoof some methods. As a normal user, there is no way

Comment: There is ANDROID_ID which stays the same if you uninstall and reinstall an app (or simply clear app data). On unrooted devices only a factory rest changes thus UD.

Comment: Would factory reset and changing ANDROID_ID do the trick?